# Unable to install Doctrine Migrations V2 in a Symfony 4.1 project

Tags: doctrine-orm, migration, symfony4

I'm trying to install Doctrine Migrations in a new Symfony 4.1 project.
I just created this proejct with composer create-project specifying the website skeleton.

From the documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html):

```
$ composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle "^2.0"
```

This fails with these errors:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle ^2.0 is satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[2.0.x-dev,
>   v2.0.0-alpha1, v2.0.0-beta1] but these conflict with your requirements
>   or minimum-stability.
>
> Problem 2
>       - symfony/orm-pack v1.0.5 requires doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle ^1.3 -> satisfiable by
>   doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.3.0, v1.3.1] but
>   these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - symfony/orm-pack v1.0.5 requires doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle ^1.3 -> satisfiable by
>   doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.3.0, v1.3.1] but
>   these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - symfony/orm-pack v1.0.5 requires doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle ^1.3 -> satisfiable by
>   doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.3.0, v1.3.1] but
>   these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - Installation request for symfony/orm-pack (locked at v1.0.5, required as *) -> satisfiable by symfony/orm-pack[v1.0.5].

I am at a loss.

Comment: I got the same error.  Looking at the composer.json file I'm not sure it is compatible with 4.1.  Might try opening an issue on github.

Comment: @Cerad, I'll be happy to open an issue. Can you provide a link to the correct github page? Thanks.

Comment: In the meantime, I've installed V1.3 which installed successfully (we'll see if it functions correctly). (composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle "^1.3")

Comment: Yep. Migrations 1.3 seems to work fine with Symfony 4.1.

Comment: not for me.. I have the same issue and 1.3 bundle is not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and here's what I did to get it working:

1. `composer unpack orm`
2. `composer require doctrine/migrations "v2.0.0-beta1"`
3. `composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle "v2.0.0-alpha1"`

As I understand it, the orm-pack was required to be unpacked so that migrations can be upgraded to match doctrine-migrations-bundle's version.

Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried steady_daddy's approach but it didn't work for me. What actually worked for me was:

1. `composer unpack orm`
2. `composer remove doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle`
3. `composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle "v2.0.0-beta2"`

Probably you also have to set the "[minimum-stability](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability)" option to "beta" in your composer.json file.

More information about unpacking the Symfony packs you can find at http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-unpack-the-packs.html